# Group by year in date field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL database which has a customer table. Some dummy data is:

```
customer_id    date
000001         2008-10-10
000002         2008-11-11
000003         2010-01-02
000004         2007-04-03
000005         2010-05-05
```

I want to run a query which will give me a result like so:

```
year    customer_count
2007    1
2008    2
2010    2
```

I know I need to use group by, however I am unable to wrap my head around how to group based on year value of a date field, and how to have them in an order.

Answer (score 8):

Extract the year from the date and group by it

```
select year(date) as year, 
       count(customer_id) as customers
from your_table
group by year
order by year asc
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`YEAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function to get the year part of the date, and use that in the grouping and ordering.

```
SELECT YEAR(date) AS year, COUNT(*) AS customer_count
FROM customer
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY year
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `EXTRACT` function to get the relevant part of the date :

```
select extract(YEAR from join_d)"Year",count(DISTINCT customer_id) "customer_count" 
from  customer 
group by year
order by year;
```